# Comparing fields in two files with calculations

Tags: bash, awk

WORKS!!

See below...

**UPDATED My Script...**

Problem is it only outputs the first line in the outside loop. Something simple is wrong, I don't see it.

This script reads from two files and does the calculations.
Here are the files...

```
$  awk -F',' '{print $1, $2, $3, $4}' s1.txt
2017 5155 41.46097500 -78.99436944
2017 5156 41.46157778 -78.99437500
2017 5157 41.46218611 -78.99437778
2017 5158 41.46278611 -78.99438056
2017 5159 41.46339722 -78.99438333
2017 5160 41.46399444 -78.99438611


$  awk -F',' '{print $11, $12}' data.txt
41.46098533 -78.99440559
41.46217481 -78.99440703
41.46158424 -78.99439119
41.46278446 -78.99439355
41.46338829 -78.99440672
41.46399091 -78.99439231
```

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { 
   while (getline < "s1.txt") {
      split($0, ft, ",")
      line =    ft[1]
      station = ft[2]
      lat1 =    ft[3]
      lon1 =    ft[4]

      while (getline < "data.txt") {
          split($0, ft, ",")
          lat2 = ft[11]
          lon2 = ft[12]

          x = (lon2 - lon1) * cos((lat1 + lat2) / 2)
          y = (lat2 - lat1)
          d = sqrt(x * x + y * y) * 6371

          print line","station","lat1","lon1","lat2","lon2","d | "sort -t, -h -k7 |head -1" 

      }
   }
}
```

Output..

```
2017,5155,41.46097500,-78.99436944,41.46098533,-78.99440559,0.198629
```

This loaded the first line from s1.txt and compared all lines in data.txt.

I need to advance s1.txt to the next line and loop it until I reach the end of s1.txt.

???

I added some print commands

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { 
   while (getline < "s1.txt") {
      split($0, ft, ",")
      line =    ft[1]
      station = ft[2]
      lat1 =    ft[3]
      lon1 =    ft[4]
      print "loop1"
      while (getline < "data.txt") {
          split($0, ft, ",")
          lat2 = ft[11]
          lon2 = ft[12]

          x = (lon2 - lon1) * cos((lat1 + lat2) / 2)
          y = (lat2 - lat1)
          d = sqrt(x * x + y * y) * 6371
          print "loop2"
          print line","station","lat1","lon1","lat2","lon2","d | "sort -t, -h -k7 |head -1" 

      }
   }
}
```

Looks like it works one time through. After that it does not enter the second loop.

```
$ resolv.awk
loop1
loop2
loop2
loop2
loop2
loop2
loop2
loop2
loop2
loop2
loop1
loop1
loop1
loop1
loop1
loop1
loop1
2017,5155,41.46097500,-78.99436944,41.46104466,-78.99446284,0.656815
```

If I use a break on the inner loop it loops correctly but the break will not let it work correctly as it takes the first line from the match file every time. I think maybe the files need to be exchanged. Inner loop for the match file and outer loop for the data.

Or some condition statement on the break.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { 
   while (getline < "s1.txt") {
      split($0, ft, ",")
      line =    ft[1]
      station = ft[2]
      lat1 =    ft[3]
      lon1 =    ft[4]
      print "loop1"
      while (getline < "data.txt") {
          split($0, ft, ",")
          lat2 = ft[11]
          lon2 = ft[12]

          x = (lon2 - lon1) * cos((lat1 + lat2) / 2)
          y = (lat2 - lat1)
          d = sqrt(x * x + y * y) * 6371
      print "loop2"
          print line","station","lat1","lon1","lat2","lon2","d 
      break
      }
   }
}

    $ resolv.awk
loop1
loop2
2017,5155,41.46097500,-78.99436944,41.46104466,-78.99446284,0.656815
loop1
loop2
2017,5156,41.46157778,-78.99437500,41.46162354,-78.9943992,0.317363
loop1
loop2
2017,5157,41.46218611,-78.99437778,41.46215576,-78.99438806,0.200558
loop1
loop2
2017,5158,41.46278611,-78.99438056,41.46281488,-78.99439355,0.195243
loop1
loop2
2017,5159,41.46339722,-78.99438333,41.46458318,-78.99436234,7.55653
loop1
loop2
2017,5160,41.46399444,-78.99438611,41.46517654,-78.99437141,7.53154
loop1
loop2
2017,5161,41.46459722,-78.99438889,41.46580453,-78.99434083,7.69578
loop1
```

**This one works..**
I will have to sort and remove duplicates on the outside of the script instead of on the inside as I originally planned.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { 
   while (getline < "s2.txt") {
      split($0, ft, ",")
      line =    ft[1]
      station = ft[2]
      lat1 =    ft[3]
      lon1 =    ft[4]
      while (getline < "data.txt") {
          split($0, ft, ",")
          lat2 = ft[11]
          lon2 = ft[12]
          ln2 =  ft[14]
          stn2 = ft[15]

          x = (lon2 - lon1) * cos((lat1 + lat2) / 2)
          y = (lat2 - lat1)
          d = sqrt(x * x + y * y) * 6371
          print line","station","lat1","lon1","ln2","stn2","lat2","lon2","d
      }

      # edited here
      close ( "data.txt" )

   }
}

2017,5155,41.46097500,-78.99436944,2017,5155,41.46104466,-78.99446284,0.656815
2017,5155,41.46097500,-78.99436944,2017,5156,41.46162354,-78.9943992,4.13473
2017,5155,41.46097500,-78.99436944,2017,5157,41.46215576,-78.99438806,7.52324
2017,5156,41.46157778,-78.99437500,2017,5155,41.46104466,-78.99446284,3.42688
2017,5156,41.46157778,-78.99437500,2017,5156,41.46162354,-78.9943992,0.317363
2017,5156,41.46157778,-78.99437500,2017,5157,41.46215576,-78.99438806,3.68293
2017,5157,41.46218611,-78.99437778,2017,5155,41.46104466,-78.99446284,7.28552
2017,5157,41.46218611,-78.99437778,2017,5156,41.46162354,-78.9943992,3.58585
2017,5157,41.46218611,-78.99437778,2017,5157,41.46215576,-78.99438806,0.200558
2017,5158,41.46278611,-78.99438056,2017,5155,41.46104466,-78.99446284,11.103
2017,5158,41.46278611,-78.99438056,2017,5156,41.46162354,-78.9943992,7.40736
2017,5158,41.46278611,-78.99438056,2017,5157,41.46215576,-78.99438806,4.01615
2017,5159,41.46339722,-78.99438333,2017,5155,41.46104466,-78.99446284,14.9938
2017,5159,41.46339722,-78.99438333,2017,5156,41.46162354,-78.9943992,11.3004
2017,5159,41.46339722,-78.99438333,2017,5157,41.46215576,-78.99438806,7.90938

 resolv.awk |sort -h -k9 -t, |awk -F',' '!_[$1$2]++' | awk -F',' '!_[$7$8]++'
2017,5157,41.46218611,-78.99437778,2017,5157,41.46215576,-78.99438806,0.200558
2017,5156,41.46157778,-78.99437500,2017,5156,41.46162354,-78.9943992,0.317363
2017,5155,41.46097500,-78.99436944,2017,5155,41.46104466,-78.99446284,0.656815
```

Comment: The `break` is in the outer loop and thus breaks it. Perhaps you mean to break the inner loop.

Comment: If I break the inner loop I get a single line from the end of s1.txt matched. If I break the outer loop I get a single line from the beginning of s1.txt matched. same with no break. seems like getline is working fine in the inner loop but not in the outer loop unless the inner loop is broken.

Comment: You might want to refactor your code to read the smaller file into memory, rather than repeatedly reading it from disk.  A common `awk` idiom for processing two files is using `NR==FNR` which will be true when you read the first file, but not for subsequent input files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you missed `close`  statement.

#! /usr/bin/awk -f

```
BEGIN { 
   while (getline < "s1.txt") {
      split($0, ft, ",")
      line =    ft[1]
      station = ft[2]
      lat1 =    ft[3]
      lon1 =    ft[4]

      while (getline < "data.txt") {
          split($0, ft, ",")
          lat2 = ft[11]
          lon2 = ft[12]

          x = (lon2 - lon1) * cos((lat1 + lat2) / 2)
          y = (lat2 - lat1)
          d = sqrt(x * x + y * y) * 6371

          print line","station","lat1","lon1","lat2","lon2","d | "sort -t, -h -k7 |head -1" 

      }

      # edited here
      close ( "data.txt" )

   }
}
```

Comment: That fixed the loop problem. Now it is a matter of the way I expected it to work. Removing the sort lets it all go out.

Comment: ' resolv.awk |sort -h -k9 -t, |awk -F',' '!_[$1$2]++' | awk -F',' '!_[$7$8]++'
2017,5157,41.46218611,-78.99437778,2017,5157,41.46215576,-78.99438806,0.200558
2017,5156,41.46157778,-78.99437500,2017,5156,41.46162354,-78.9943992,0.317363
2017,5155,41.46097500,-78.99436944,2017,5155,41.46104466,-78.99446284,0.656815
'